# Get objectAtIndex from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, nsmutabledictionary

In my app, I'm working with `UISearchBar` where user will search from an `NSMutableArray` by searching with user name. Here is my method for searching user from `NSMutableArray`

```
- (void)searchTableList
{
    NSString *searchString = searchBar.text;

    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in contentList)
    {

        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"username"];
        [searchArray addObject:array];
    }

    for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
    {
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [filteredContentList addObject:sTemp];
    }
}
```

And Here is how I'm configuring `UITableView` for showing search results

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchListTableViewCell";
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[contentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    SearchListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchListTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
        cell = (SearchListTableViewCell*)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:239.0/255 green:239.0/255 blue:239.0/255 alpha:1];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (isSearching)
    {
        cell.friendName.text = [filteredContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSMutableArray *searchImageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in contentList)
        {

            NSArray *imageArray=[dictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail_path_150_150"];
            NSLog(@"image arrayt is %@",imageArray);
            [searchImageArray addObject:imageArray];
        }

        for (NSString *imageS in searchImageArray) {
            NSRange title=[imageS rangeOfString:cell.friendName.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (title.length>0) {
                [filteredImage addObject:imageS];
            }
        }
        NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/get_image?avatar=%@",BaseURL,[filteredImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        url=[url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"/"];
        UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:
                            [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                             [NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
        [cell.friendProfileImage setImage:myImage];
        NSLog(@"filtered Image data %lu",(unsigned long)filteredImage.count);
        NSLog(@"filtered content list data %lu",(unsigned long)filteredContentList.count);
    }
    else
    {
        cell.friendName.text =[dict objectForKey:@"username"];
        NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/get_image?avatar=%@",BaseURL,[dict objectForKey:@"thumbnail_path_150_150"]];
        url=[url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"/"];
        UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:
                            [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                             [NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
        [cell.friendProfileImage setImage:myImage];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Now I want to fetch the rest data of searched user name from `NSMutableDictionary`. Here is my dictionary.

```
(
        {
        jid = "hey@196.0.0.1";
        "thumbnail_path_150_150" = "E\\path\\to\\getImage\\files\\heythumbnail";
        username = hey;
    },
        {
        jid = "tweety@196.0.0.1";
        "thumbnail_path_150_150" = "E:\\path\\to\\getImage\\files\\tweetythumbnail";
        username = tweety;
    }
)
```

Here I want to get the image of searched user. If user searches hey, It must show `"thumbnail_path_150_150"
="E\\path\\to\\getImage\\files\\heythumbnail";` this image on tableViewCell. I tried my code for setting image But it replaces image when two users have same name. Like if one user is Ray and another is Blueray , then it changes the image of both. I know i wrote too much. But I'm really confused at this point. Please anyone help solving this issue.

Comment: you have an array of dictionaries and want to search for matching array items .. just clarifying what I see above

Comment: @Daij-Djan, Yes exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply a `NSPredicate` to filter your array and then use this array to populate the tableView

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username contains[c] %@",_search_bar.text];
NSArray  *filteredArray = [yourMainArray  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"here is the filteredCandyArray%@",filteredCandyArray);

//set it to the array you use to fill the table
_dataSourceArray = _filteredCandyArray;

//go!    
[_yourTable reloadData];
```

String comparisons are by default case and diacritic sensitive. You can modify an operator using the key characters c and d within square braces to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively, for example firstName BEGINSWITH[cd] $FIRST_NAME.

BEGINSWITH: The left-hand expression begins with the right-hand expression.
CONTAINS: The left-hand expression contains the right-hand expression.
ENDSWITH: The left-hand expression ends with the right-hand expression.
LIKE: The left hand expression equals the right-hand expression: ? and * are allowed as wildcard characters, where ? matches 1 character and * matches 0 or more characters.
MATCHES: The left hand expression equals the right hand expression . 
or further details please visit http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

Comment: contains [c] would return all the elements where it finds ray so this is case insensitive search. Please update your answer

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to do this is by using predicates and with a little modifications your code can go somewhat like this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username == %@", @"ray"];
NSArray *searchedArray = [rootArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The above code will only return values where username is ray and not Ray or RAY etc

Comment: @Sushil You can add this code where you are actual doing the search part, If i am not wrong then inside your searchTableList method should do the trick. 
The searchedArray would be the array which you can provide to your table delegate and datasource methods should work just fine
Do let me know if this answer helps

Comment: I tried your code. The problem with this is , It doesn't show image until user types complete name in searchBar. But with AHSAN NAZIR RAJA's code, It is showing correct image.

Comment: @Sushil Maybe i did not detail it much but in earlier comments mentioned to use the final array as your datasource anyways glad i could be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `Search Bar and Search Display Controller` rather than `Search Bar`.

Also have a look at the following code, it covers everything you want.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark
#pragma mark - View Lifecycle

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *dic1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"India",        @"IN", @"+91",  nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CountryId", @"CountryName", @"CountryCode", @"ISDCode", nil]];
    NSDictionary *dic2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2", @"Australia",    @"AU", @"+61",  nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CountryId", @"CountryName", @"CountryCode", @"ISDCode", nil]];
    NSDictionary *dic3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3", @"New Zealand",  @"NZ", @"+64",  nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CountryId", @"CountryName", @"CountryCode", @"ISDCode", nil]];
    NSDictionary *dic4 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"South Africa", @"SA", @"+27",  nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CountryId", @"CountryName", @"CountryCode", @"ISDCode", nil]];
    NSDictionary *dic5 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"5", @"England",      @"EN", @"+44",  nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CountryId", @"CountryName", @"CountryCode", @"ISDCode", nil]];
    NSDictionary *dic6 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"6", @"Israel",       @"IS", @"+972", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CountryId", @"CountryName", @"CountryCode", @"ISDCode", nil]];
    NSDictionary *dic7 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"7", @"Afghanistan",  @"AF", @"+93",  nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CountryId", @"CountryName", @"CountryCode", @"ISDCode", nil]];
    NSDictionary *dic8 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"8", @"Ireland",      @"IR", @"+353", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CountryId", @"CountryName", @"CountryCode", @"ISDCode", nil]];
    NSDictionary *dic9 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"9", @"China",        @"CN", @"+86",  nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CountryId", @"CountryName", @"CountryCode", @"ISDCode", nil]];

    arrTotalCountries = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dic1, dic2, dic3, dic4, dic5, dic6, dic7, dic8, dic9, nil];
}


#pragma mark
#pragma mark - UITableView delegate, datasource methods

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
        return [arrFilteredCountries count];
    }
    else{
        return [arrTotalCountries count];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%ld%ld",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *dicCountry;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        dicCountry = [arrFilteredCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        dicCountry = [arrTotalCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    NSString *strShow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",[dicCountry objectForKey:@"CountryName"],[dicCountry objectForKey:@"ISDCode"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = strShow;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSDictionary *dicCountry;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        dicCountry = [arrFilteredCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        dicCountry = [arrTotalCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    NSString *countryName    = [dicCountry objectForKey:@"CountryName"];
    NSString *CountryISDCode = [dicCountry objectForKey:@"ISDCode"];

    [self showAlertWithTitle:countryName message:CountryISDCode];
}


#pragma mark
#pragma mark - Other method Implementation

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF.CountryName BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (SELF.ISDCode CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText, searchText];
    arrFilteredCountries = [arrTotalCountries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

-(void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}


#pragma mark
#pragma mark - UISearchbar controller delegate

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}


#pragma mark
#pragma mark - Memory management

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Also add a comment in case, anyone stuck at some point. I have implemented this and it works nicely. It's a short and best way to add search function to your Table view.

Comment: Thanks @pratik for complete demo, But `Search Display Controller` is deprecated in iOS8.